# Daily (monthly) limit on firebase

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I didn't understand the firebase limitation. For example, 1 gb of free service per month in the firebase. 1gb for each app or for all apps in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 GB For 1 Project
For Every Month
Even If You are in paid Plan You will get This Free

Comment: so 1 gb is given for each project? is not a general limitation?

Comment: Yes It is not on apps it count on project only

Comment: What is the difference between an app and a project?

Comment: One project can contain multiple apps. You can create only project in firebase. And then you are adding your app.